# GUI - Changing the color of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, background, jframe

I'm new in Java and I need your help in implementing a GUI. Below is a Guessing Game code. It works.

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.util.Random;

  public class GuessGame extends JFrame {
     private JTextField guessTextField;
     private JLabel introLabel, guessLabel, clueLabel;
     private JButton enterB, playAgainB;

     private int randomNumber;

     public GuessGame() {
        super("Guessing Game!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Creates components
        enterB = new JButton("Guess");
        playAgainB = new JButton("Quit");
        introLabel = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000.");
        guessLabel = new JLabel("Can you guess my number? Please enter your guess:");

        clueLabel = new JLabel("");
       // comment2 = new JLabel(" ");
        guessTextField = new JTextField(5);

        //content pane
        Container c = getContentPane();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //adding component to the pane
        c.add(introLabel);
        c.add(guessLabel);
        c.add(guessTextField);
        //c.add(comment2);
        c.add(enterB);
        c.add(playAgainB);
        c.add(clueLabel);

        //enterB.setMnemonic('G');
        //playAgainB.setMnemonic('Q');

        setSize(350, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        //setResizable(false);

        initializeNumber();

        //creating the handler
        GuessButtonHandler ghandler = new GuessButtonHandler(); //instantiate new object
        enterB.addActionListener(ghandler); // add event listener

        QuitButtonHandler qhandler = new QuitButtonHandler();
        playAgainB.addActionListener(qhandler);
     }

     private void initializeNumber() {
        randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1;
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
     }

     class QuitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.exit(0);
        }
     }

     class GuessButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           int getUserInput;
           int diff;
           int Difference;
           try {
              getUserInput = Integer.parseInt(guessTextField.getText().trim());      

              if (getUserInput == randomNumber) {
                  clueLabel.setText("                              Correct!");
              }
              if (getUserInput > randomNumber) {
                 clueLabel.setText("                           Too High");
              } else {
                 clueLabel.setText("                           Too Low");
              }


           } 
           catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
              clueLabel.setText("Enter a VALID number!");
           }
        }


     }



     public static void main(String args[]) {
        //instantiate gueesgame object
         GuessGame app = new GuessGame();

     }
  }
```

However, the color of the window should change into red or blue. Please help me with this code. I'm new in Java and it's syntax. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
current = Integer.parseInt(guessTextField.getText().trim()); 
if (!firstTime) {
    if (getUserInput > previous) {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    } else {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}
```

where `firstTime` and `previous` are class member variables.

Don't forget to assign `previous` if the `getUserInput == randomNumber` is **not** met.

**Update:**

You are setting the background blue twice:

```
if (getUserInput < randomNumber) {
   clueLabel.setText("Too Low");
   getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue); <------ remove this extra call
   previous = getUserInput;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Which part should I put this? Or what loop should I make? :)

Comment: This goes in your `GuessButtonHandler`

Comment: Thank you sir! I did that (please see edit) and when I input 12, and the next input is 13, it is still color blue. It just turns to red if the input is higher than the random number. What is wrong with my edit? :)

Comment: See my update. Also `previous` should be a **class member variable**

Comment: Oh yeah! That just occurred to me. Thank you very much! I am really sorry, sir, for my stubborness. If it's all the same to you, how can I **not** change the color when the first guess is input? The color should only be changed during the second input. I'm am so new in programming Java and I'm confused. Thank you!

Comment: You can use a simple boolean at class level. Set to false after first pass.

Answer (score 1):

A code is better than thousand words.....

```
 if (current_Input > previous) {
    c.setBackground(Color.red);
 } else {
    c.setBackground(Color.blue);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! How do you think I can declare current_Input and previous if there is a GuessButtonHandler ever click? :)